# PA/Docusign: Add tab for recipient - Multi-line text?

Tags: docusignapi, power-automate, docusignconnect

I'm building a flow in Power Automate using the DocuSign connector. I've pulled a set of names from my SharePoint list and created a multi-line string variable (varNames) which displays in compose like this:

John Doe
Mary Joe
Gary Moe

I would like to pass this list of names in the same format to my DocuSign template. I'm utilizing the "Add tabs for recipient" action using tab type "text". However, when I pass varNames in the "tabs value" field, it does not respect the line breaks in my variable and displays in a single line.

Does anybody know how to insert line breaks in a text tab through the "add tab for recipient" action?

I've inserting line breaks in different ways using carriage returns, "\n", "
" within the variable in the "tabs value" input field itself. No matter what I try, the tab seems to always display as a single line.

Answer (score 0):

```
            DisableAutoSize = "false",
            Height = "40",
            Width = "200",
```

Add the above just for testing. Note that \n is correct to add a new line, but if the tab is not change to disable auto sizing or sized correctly, this may not work. You need to ensure the tab has the size to support multiple lines.